# How to iterate through JSON array from n1ql query?

Tags: c#, .net, json, parsing, couchbase

so I'm using couchbase queue to Enqueue my beacon information. I'm trying to use n1ql query for my get method and I'm having trouble getting all the information. I realized I'm only getting the first beacon entry because result.Rows returns one element, an array of BeaconInfoN1ql. I wanted to iterate through that array and add each to a list.

```
try {
     var cluster = new Cluster(new ClientConfiguration());
     using (var bucket = cluster.OpenBucket("BeaconInfoN1ql"))
     {
         string query = "SELECT * FROM `BeaconInfoN1ql`";
         var queryRequest = new QueryRequest(query);
         var result = bucket.Query<dynamic>(queryRequest);
     foreach (var row in result.Rows)
      {

          int i = 0;
          var beacon = new Beacon()
          {
              SerialNumber = row.BeaconInfoN1ql[i].serialNumber,
              ReceivedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row.BeaconInfoN1ql[i].receivedDate),
              ReceiverId = row.BeaconInfoN1ql[i].receiverId,
              Distance = Convert.ToDouble(row.BeaconInfoN1ql[i].distance),
              Rssi = Convert.ToInt32(row.BeaconInfoN1ql[i].rssi),
              NewDistance = Convert.ToDouble(row.BeaconInfoN1ql[i].newDistance),
              DistanceTesting = Convert.ToDouble(row.BeaconInfoN1ql[i].distanceTesting),
          };
          i++;
          _beaconsList.Add(beacon);
      }
 }
 return _beaconsList;
```

my result.Rows looks like this

result.Rows=

```
{{
"BeaconInfoN1ql": [
{
"distance": 2.2705747109792007,
"distanceTesting": 22,
"newDistance": 22,
"receivedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
"receiverId": "42008780c4b9b329",
"rssi": -73,
"serialNumber": "888"
},
{
"distance": 2.2705747109792007,
"distanceTesting": 22,
"newDistance": 22,
"receivedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
"receiverId": "42008780c4b9b329",
"rssi": -73,
"serialNumber": "888"
},
{
"distance": 2.2705747109792007,
"distanceTesting": 22,
"newDistance": 22,
"receivedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
"receiverId": "42008780c4b9b329",
"rssi": -73,
"serialNumber": "888"
},
{
"distance": 2.2705747109792007,
"distanceTesting": 22,
"newDistance": 22,
"receivedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
"receiverId": "42008780c4b9b329",
"rssi": -73,
"serialNumber": "888"
},
]
}}
```

I'm not sure about how to make the second foreach/for loop to iterate through all the keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For iterating JSON, I like to use dynamics. Here's an example:

```
var result = new Result()
{
    Rows = @"{
        'BeaconInfoN1ql': [
            {
                 'distance': 2.2705747109792007,
                 'distanceTesting': 22,
                 'newDistance': 22,
                 'receivedDate': '0001-01-01T00:00:00',
                 'receiverId': '42008780c4b9b329',
                 'rssi': -73,
                 'serialNumber': '888'
            }
        ]
    }" //other entries omitted for brevity
};

dynamic parsedRows = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result.Rows);
foreach (var entry in parsedRows.BeaconInfoN1ql)
    Debug.Write(entry.distance);
```

NOTE: I got rid of the double curly braces from your output in my example.

Comment: I tried that, I can't deserialize result.Rows, it gives System.Collections.Generic.List<dynamic> to string . I think one of the reason is maybe because the json has two bracket '{{' not one? I can't use split() because result is a iQueryResult<dynamic> and that doesn't have split function.